# Using 'Potential Duplicate' flag to serve a useful purpose. 'Relevant Solutions' tag?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

At times I try to use the 'Potential Duplicate' flag and more often than not, when I do, my intentions are to be helpful to the author of the question by pointing out to them another similar post in which I found an answer to their question.  Occasionally I'd certainly feel safe to state that it's definitely a duplicate but more often I'd agree that they aren't mirror duplicates.. but depends what you consider a duplicate.

If it's not the exact same question but the context of the question is the same or the questions are seemingly different subjects but the question boils down to the same issue and solution is it a duplicate?  Is flagging a duplicate post meant to be for the benefit of the person who asked the question (a polite slap on the wrist) or is it supposed to be for the purpose of cross-linking content and making SO easier for people to search through to discover their own answers to questions without having to ask the same thing a million different ways.

The way I've interpreted it is if there is another question which is similar and if the author could formulate a solution to their problem by reading the answers to someone elses similar but not exact same problem, then it's a duplicate and I flag it as such with the intent of being helpful and pointing out a resource so whether they have found an answer to their question or not, it cross-links the two separate pages so anyone who comes across it in the future researching their own problem can see the reference and potentially find it useful.

ON the same note, I have at times done this in events where I saw duplicate questions but the older of the two had no answers, the newer of the two had great answers so I would mark the older one as a duplicate of the newer one as a reference to where the answer could be found.  Obviously it's not really proper though because technically the answered question would be a duplicate of the unanswered older one.  But if I flagged it the other way around it would be less effective as a reference.

Ultimately, I've just stopped marking duplicates for the most part because my interpretation of it's purpose seems to be incorrect and doesn't seem welcome.  But in doing so, I think its a shame because if I'm browsing old QA's trying to find a solution to a problem I'm having, I think it'd be much more useful to see cross-links to relevant questions rather than just the links to similar questions that shows up on the sidebar and seems to be populated autonomously by title keywords.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with marking older questions as duplicates of newer ones. As for the rest of your post it's unclear whether you're after some validation of your workflow or whether you have an actual featue request, and what exactly it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Leave a comment containing a link to the other question (or even to a specific answer).

Above the automatically generated list of related questions appears a list of "Linked" questions, which your link will affect.

(Note that your comment should be more than just a link.  Include 1-2 sentences how the other information could help.)